# Strange results by integrating Abs[Sin[a - t]]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, conditional

I have a (simple) integral with a unknown parameter `a`:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin(a-t)|dt$$
One can observe that it is just two times the area under sin curve from $0$ to $\pi$ and the result is $4$, `Integrate` agrees with it when given exact values of `a`.

However, when I try to evaluate this integral directly, `Integrate[Abs@Sin[a - t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` won't finish running. When I try to give it assumptions, interesting results appeared:

```
Table[Integrate[Abs@Sin[a - t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> a > i], {i, -8, 8, 2}]
Table[Integrate[Abs@Sin[a - t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> a < i], {i, -8, 8, 2}]
```

[image]

It just gives $0$, and generates the condition with the nearest feasible $k\pi,k\in \mathbb Z$.

I am using version 11.1 on OSX, is there any problem with my usage? How can I get the result $4$?

Comment: A very limited solution: `Assuming[0 <= a < 2 π, FullSimplify[Integrate[PiecewiseExpand[Abs[Sin[a - t]]], {t, 0, 2 π}]]]`

Comment: @J.M. Nice observation for the assumption intervals. Now I found `Integrate[Abs[Sin[a - t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},  Assumptions -> 0 < a < 23 Pi]` generates `Boole` expressions that can be simplified to correct result, while parameters larger than 24, `Integrate[Abs[Sin[a - t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Assumptions -> 0 < a < 24 Pi]` directly gives wrong result. It could be that Mathematica gives up because the increasing size of the `Boole` expressions.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  Wrapping the result in an unnecessary `ConditionalExpression` is excusable, but giving an incorrect answer is not.

Comment: @mikado I agree, I have reported this issue to support: case 3869442

Answer (score 3):

Extending the answer of @J. M.♦  you can write the `a` as `a == b + k * 2 * π`     and you will get the right general solution:

```
    Assuming[0 <= b < 2 π && k ∈ Integers, 
             Simplify[Integrate[Abs[Sin[b + k 2 π - t]], {t, 0, 2 π}]]]

    (*  4  *)
```

Comment: Hah, manually taking a `Mod[]`...

Comment: Actually given the parameter a short interval assumption, e.g. `Integrate[Abs[Sin[a - t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},  Assumptions -> 0 < a < 2 Pi] // FullSimplify` is enough to get the correct answer.

Comment: The aim should not be to get the correct answer for a restricted range of a, but for all real a. Therefore  a == b + k * 2 * Pi, which is valid for all real a.